# Where should I initialize a web form user control in it's container page?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, pageload, aspx-user-control

I have a web form called `addresspage.aspx` which contains a user control called `addresscontrol.ascx`. There are properties exposed by `addresscontrol.ascx` like `ZipCode`.

I have to achieve two things.

- Read the `ZipCode` query string from the URL (`http://localhost/checkout/addresspage?zipcode=00000`) and populate the `addresscontrol`
- If there is no ZipCode in the query string, redirect to the cart page.

Where can I do the above two in the aspx page cycle events in the `addresspage.aspx`? I know `Page_Load` and `Page_Init` but don't know where for the above two.

Comment: `Page_Load`. And if the redirect is only needed when `addresscontrol.ascx` is used somewhere on the site then in there is fine. If the redirect is only going to be used on `addresspage.aspx`, put it there.

Comment: Do you mean, do the redirect in the ```addresscontrol.ascx``` if there is no ```ZipCode```? Or should that check be in the ```addresspage.ascx```?

Comment: If the zipcode field is in the ascx, and you need the redirect everywhere the ascx is used is necessary then put it in there.

Comment: is it working??

Comment: The redirect is working. But I don't know the proper place to retrieve the ```ZipCode``` from the query string. Currently I set the property called ```ZipCode``` of the ```addresscontrol``` and the control uses that property inside and redirect. Should I move that to the ```addresscontrol``` also?